# After upgrade to Ubuntu 18, apticron email subject is not showing the System anymore

Tags: 18.04, apticron

We have apticron on our servers that will send emails when there are pending package upgrades. The emails have a subject like this:

> 30 Ubuntu package update(s) for name-of-server

After the major upgrade from Ubuntu 16 to Ubuntu 18 the server name is not showing anymore in the email subject:

> 30 Ubuntu package update(s) for

The `apticron.conf` didn't change during the upgrade.  Only `EMAIL` is set, everything else is commented out. Also the part for `SYSTEM`:

```
# Set SYSTEM if you would like apticron to use something other than the output
# of "hostname -f" for the system name in the mails it generates. This option
# overrides the ALL_FQDNS above.
#
# SYSTEM="foobar.example.com"
```

`hostname -f` is working fine and outputs the system name as excepted.

Does anybody have an idea how this could be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime I found the solution. In the `apticron.conf` set `SYSTEM` like this:

```
SYSTEM=$(/bin/hostname -f)
```